# Google map not working in my app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps

In my applicaion I would like to access google map api for that purpose I have used com.google.android.maps.MapView my app running with out ANY exception but unfortunatly its not loading here I attached my tried code.

**map.xml**

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout
>   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>   android:layout_width="match_parent"
>   android:layout_height="match_parent">   
>   <com.google.android.maps.MapView        android:id="@+id/kioskMapView"
>       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>       android:layout_height="fill_parent"         android:enabled="true"
>       android:clickable="true"
>       android:apiKey="AIzaSyAND7gp2wVtfHwkyEAC6UgiYULyIAqpc0I" />     
> </RelativeLayout>
```

**class name** 
**MapViewingActivity.java**

> 

```
public class  MapViewingActivity extends MapActivity {   GoogleMap
> map;  private GoogleMap mapView;    //  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
> @Override    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>        setContentView(R.layout.map);
>                
>            }
> 
> 
>    
> 
> 
> @Override protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {  // TODO
> Auto-generated method stub    return false; } }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try generating a new API key using the SHA1 from the debug keystore in the .android directory; it is called debug.keystore and should be located in the following directory:

OS X and Linux: `~/.android/`

Windows Vista and Windows 7: `C:\Users\your_user_name\.android\`

Once you locate it you can get the SHA1 with the following command:

OS X and Linux: `keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

Windows Vista and Windows 7: `keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`